# Transfer TextBox1 Text from Form1 to TextBox3 Text in Form2

Tags: c#

Exactly what the title says I don't know how to transfer text from Form1 to form2...

I have tried multiple methods which have failed.

Please help and thank you

Comment: I tried all of those methods nothing works...

Comment: I don't think you try.There are thousands of question on stackoverflow about this

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it using Form2 constructor function. In Form1:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this.textBox1.Text);

form2.ShowDialog();
```

In Form2:

```
public class Form2
{
    public Form2(string comingText)
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        this.textBox3.Text = comingText;
    }
}
```